# Is prayer accepted if your hair isn't covered?

Tags: salat, women

If I am out of home and do not have cover for my hair and it is time for prayer will it not be accepted if I pray?

Comment: Pray without covering your hair?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it mandatory for men to cover hair(head), while praying](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/971/is-it-mandatory-for-men-to-cover-hairhead-while-praying)

Comment: question ask for women not for men, so this is not possible duplicate of your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
              In the name of Allah, The most compassionate, the most merciful
```

Based on what you inquired that:

> If I am out of home and do not have cover for my hair and it is time
>   for prayer will it not be accepted if I pray?

The answer is that covering the hairs for women is considered as a wajib (obligatory) practice and actually you ought to cover your hairs during the Salah (prayer). (Although it is counted as a wajib act to cover your hairs in front of non-mahram as well).

**Consequently** it seems that your salah or prayer wouldn’t be OK/accepted and I reckon you must repeat it again as Qaza. Good luck. May Allah guide all of us

**Reference:**

[http://www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa1280)

Answer (score 0):

It is NOT wajib, however it is Sunnah of our Holy Prophet Muhammad صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم

Prayer is accepted although your hairs are not covered, however keeping it like this every time while offering Salah is not good and it will be counted as sin.