# Is there a ruling that says a man has to wear a head cover, in general or during prayer?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sunnah, men, clothing

I understand that there is no mention in the Quran or the Hadith of a head covering for males. It is a custom learned from the Prophet and is there in the Sunnah.

I would like to know if there is today a law that says a man has to wear a head cover, in general or during prayer?

Comment: Relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27819/imam-shafi-regarding-head-covering-of-male http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24539/why-when-and-what-is-the-meaning-of-covering-the-head-for-men http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28902/headcovering-for-men-in-islam-required http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/971/is-it-obligatory-for-muslim-men-to-cover-their-heads-while-praying?lq=1