# Is it permissible for men to pray without headcover?

Tags: salat, clothing

Is it allowed for men to pray (salaat) without headcover?
I saw many who pray with cover and many who pray without it and I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Isn't this covered in the answers of [Is it better to cover the head with a turban?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45884/is-it-better-to-cover-the-head-with-a-turban), [Is it obligatory for Muslim men to cover their heads while praying?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/971/is-it-obligatory-for-muslim-men-to-cover-their-heads-while-praying) or [What is a reliable reference for “covering of the head during salah or otherwise is mubah” by men?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27819/what-is-a-reliable-reference-for-covering-of-the-head-during-salah-or-otherwise?)

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you

Comment: Instead of deleting your question you could mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Done. Thank you.